# Pattern match certain characters after last slash

Tags: bash, regex, find, sed

I'm trying to do the following: list files or directories containing certain characters then from the last slash in the path search for particular characters and replace them with a `-`.

I built the following on regexpr but it does nothing with `sed`:

```
find . -name "*[<>:\\|?]*" | while read -r; do mv "${REPLY}" \
"`echo ${REPLY} | sed "s/([^/]+$)*([<>:\\|?])/-/g"`"; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something cleaner like:

```
find ... |
while read -r f; do
    dir=$(dirname "$f")
    old_name=$(basename "$f")
    new_name=$(echo "$old_name" | tr '<>:\\|?' '-')
    mv "$dir/$old_name" "$dir/$new_name"
done
```